# data stored in cache is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, caching, null

I'm working on a web project. i want to store my data (coming from WCFservice). then when a request comes from client i want to check whether database value is changed or not. i am making this check via a WCF method. when the time field in cache data is not equal to time value coming from WCF method, code is supposed to call the WCF method to get new data from database. new data will be stored in cache and also displays on page.

Noooow... :/ i run project display my xxx page, then display another page, then re-display my xxx page and what is that!!! my data (stored in cache) is absolutely, really, very NULL... code is here: i will be really happy about hearing your perfect suggestion people. why should it be null, how can i retrieve it from cache. 1st method is in wcf, 2nd method is already the load of the problematic page

```
public MeasurementSystemPageWcf GetActiveSystemMeasurementPage(bool RequestOnlyInfo)
{
    Session session = DBUtil.GetSession();
    XPClassInfo MeasurementSystemPageClass = session.GetClassInfo(typeof(MeasurementSystemPage));
    string QCriteria = "ISACTIVE =='true'";
    CriteriaOperator criteria = CriteriaOperator.Parse(QCriteria);
    SortingCollection sortProps = new SortingCollection(null);
    sortProps.Add(new SortProperty("", SortingDirection.Ascending));
    CollectionCriteriaPatcher patcher = new CollectionCriteriaPatcher(false, session.TypesManager);
    ICollection MeasurementSystemPageCollection = session.GetObjects(MeasurementSystemPageClass, criteria, sortProps, 0, patcher, true);
    MeasurementSystemPageWcf RetVal = new MeasurementSystemPageWcf();
    if (MeasurementSystemPageCollection != null && MeasurementSystemPageCollection.Count != 0)
    {
        if (!RequestOnlyInfo)
        {
            foreach (MeasurementSystemPage item in MeasurementSystemPageCollection)
            {
                // sadece bir tane aktif sayfa gelmesi gerektiği varsayılarak kolleksiyondaki ilk sayfa alınacak. break ile sağlanıyor
                RetVal.PAGEHEADER = item.PAGEHEADER;
                RetVal.CONTENT = item.CONTENT;
                RetVal.CREATEDATE = item.CREATEDATE;
                RetVal.EDITDATE = item.EDITDATE;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (RequestOnlyInfo)
        {
            foreach (MeasurementSystemPage item in MeasurementSystemPageCollection)
            {
                // sadece bir tane aktif sayfa gelmesi gerektiği varsayılarak kolleksiyondaki ilk sayfa alınacak. break ile sağlanıyor
                RetVal.EDITDATE = item.EDITDATE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        RetVal.ER.HasError = true;
        RetVal.ER.ErrorMethod = "MeasurementSystemPageWcf GetActiveSetMeasurementPage()";
        RetVal.ER.ErrorMessage = "Henüz İçerik Girilmemiş";
    }
    return RetVal;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XSensServiceClient client = new XSensServiceClient();
    MeasurementSystemPageWcf page_in_cache = (MeasurementSystemPageWcf)Cache["MeasurementSystemPage"];
    if (page_in_cache == null)
    {
        MeasurementSystemPageWcf active_page = client.GetActiveSystemMeasurementPage(false);
        if (active_page.ER.HasError)
        {
            lbl_Body.Text = active_page.ER.ErrorMessage;
            Page.Title = active_page.ER.ErrorMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            Cache.Insert("MeasurementSystemPage", active_page, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
            //Cache["MeasurementSystemPage"] = active_page;
            Page.Title = active_page.PAGEHEADER;
            lbl_Body.Text = active_page.CONTENT;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MeasurementSystemPageWcf active_page_from_wcf = client.GetActiveSystemMeasurementPage(true); // buraya sadece edit zamanını çeken bir method yazılacak, her karşılaştırmada bütün sayfa verisini çekmemek için.
        MeasurementSystemPageWcf active_page_from_cache = (MeasurementSystemPageWcf)Cache["MeasurementSystemPage"];
        if (active_page_from_cache.EDITDATE < active_page_from_wcf.EDITDATE)
        {
            MeasurementSystemPageWcf updated_page = client.GetActiveSystemMeasurementPage(false);
            Cache.Insert("MeasurementSystemPage", updated_page, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
            Page.Title = updated_page.PAGEHEADER;
            lbl_Body.Text = updated_page.CONTENT;
        }
        else
        {
            Page.Title = active_page_from_cache.PAGEHEADER;
            lbl_Body.Text = active_page_from_cache.CONTENT;
        }
    }
```

web.config is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>

    <!--caching nodu sonradan eklendi-->
    <caching>
      <cache disableExpiration="true"/>
    </caching>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v13.1.Core, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <devExpress>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies=""/>
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true"/>
    <settings rightToLeft="false" doctypeMode="Xhtml"/>
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl=""/>
  </devExpress>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IXSensService"  allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1/XSensWCFService/XSENSWCFService.XSensService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IXSensService"
          contract="XSensService.IXSensService" name="WSHttpBinding_IXSensService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

What does DbUtil.GetSession() look like? The problem could be there.
you are not specifying if you are using the Session State in ASP.NET to hold your session and you also should post your web.config session state settings to see if it is configured correctly and enabled

also HOW are you storing data in the cache?

Comment: hi Ahmed, 
  Session session = DBUtil.GetSession();
line is totally about the DevExpress XPO (an ORM library) feauture. actuaaly i do not think its a problematic thing.  
Cache.Insert("MeasurementSystemPage", active_page, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null); line is writing data to cache

Comment: i have add web.config as you asked

Comment: Thanks. My bad - I didn't see the scrollbar in your original code so I can look further down the code :) have you tried using Session instead of Cache? take a look at this for cache parameters. people DO get the absolute and sliding expiration mixed up sometimes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491414.aspx

Comment: Since session will be disposed when the user closes browser, that idea will not work as performance jumping as server cache. So i did not want get in the way of using session. I also want to mention. "session" statement in code is not the "Session" that is user for state management.

Comment: Right exactly. The point I was making was that I was not sure if you were confusing Cache and Session :)

Comment: ahaaa :) nope, i definitely need caching the data  (an object instanced from a class) into memory of the server... i do not know why not working... :(

Comment: I've done Cache before and never had issues. Have you tried with a plain basic ASP.NET app with very very simplistic approach to see if there is something else causing the problem? It will help troubleshoot the problem. Ideally I would like to have the solution myself so I can debug effectively and post back for all the result of the problem and solution.

Comment: solution is about to reach 850 Mbytes.. :) i will try that way. Now starting a seperate asp.net project to test in new solution.